# What does "too by the numbers" mean?

Tags: expressions

I've read the phrase:

> The book was ok but a bit **too by the numbers**.

What does "too by the numbers" mean?

Searching for it in Google gives [286,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q="too+by+the+numbers"), but can't find a definition for it.

Comment: Please provide context - and preferably a link - to the source of your phrase.  We cannot simply magic a meaning with no context!

Comment: It should have been written "a bit too by-the-numbers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **by the numbers** PHRASE
>   *North American*
>   In accordance with a rigidly followed set of rules.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by_the_numbers)

I assume you already know the meaning of **too**.

Comment: But when used as an adjective it should be hyphenated.